# How to make custom shape button in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am trying to create an app. I need button something like this :

[image]

Can any one help me to create a button like this ?

EDIT: I think, I might have confused with my question laguage, I am more interested in the drawable part and placement of those images in the layout, can you please help me with that only.

Comment: Have a look at https://github.com/medyo/fancybuttons and use/modify it to make whatever shape button you want to make.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a Linear Layout with vertical orientation that contains ImageViews?

Answer (score 0):

First, make A few Images with the buttons in their pressed and unpressed states.
Then Make a **vertical LinearLayout** with **ImageViews**.
To reverence an image from R.drawable just paste your btn images into your projects drawable folder and rebuild.
 Then attach an Onclick listener to each imageview:

```
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.myImageId);
img.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
       //change to pressed state
       img.setImageResource(R.drawable.my_pressed_image);
       //do action
    }
});
```

To rotate make use of code below:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
img.setScaleType(ScaleType.MATRIX);   //required
matrix.postRotate((float) angle, pivX, pivY);
img.setImageMatrix(matrix);
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do what I think you are asking is to set the button to an image. You could choose the image you want and the size.

To do this, you would want to set the button using ImageButton.

```
final ImageButton next = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.Button01) ;
Drawable d = Drawable.createFromPath("@drawable/imageForButton");
next.enter.setImageDrawable(d);
```

It is hard to answer this question though due to the fact that there is none of your source code to see.